# How to repeat same values in x axis of matlab figures?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two functions which their 'x' are between 1 & 30 (1<=x<=30) and each of them has its own 'y'. I want to plot them in a same diagram and draw a vertical line between them (separate them):

```
1<=x<=30 for function 1
x=31 separator
32<=x<=61 for function 2
```

This is the code:

```
y1=[6.5107   28.1239   15.0160   24.9586   17.6224   12.7936   21.9143    7.7560   27.4761    3.1279    8.3063   17.4207 8.3265    0.7540   13.2846   22.8183   25.7289   13.5553   18.0556   19.1853   20.2442    9.0290    5.3196    2.5757 21.6273    8.9054    2.0535    5.0569   22.7735   14.7483];
y2=[13.5876    5.7935    6.4742         0    7.7878         0    8.6912    0.4459   11.9369   10.4926    9.2844   10.4645 4.0736    9.0897    8.4051    0.7690   15.9073    3.7413    8.5098    9.7112    1.3231    8.5113    8.7681    4.1696 12.9530    0.6313   19.9750    0.0664    9.9677   10.1181];
%function 1
bar(1:30,y1,'r');
hold on
% a vertical line from x=31
plot([31 31],get(gca,'ylim'))
%function 2
bar(32:61,y2,'b');
```

But when I plot them, the x axis of function 1 (left function) in our diagram is 1:30 and the x axis of function 2 (right function) in our diagram is 32:61.
But I want to show the x axis values of both of them as 1:30 and not one as 1:30 and the other as 32:61. (Please see the attachment). How can I do that? [image]

Comment: It can be done via the `xticklabel` property of the axes, or more directly with the [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html) function. Post a minimal example if you want more detailed help

Comment: Use subplot and turn off ytick and yticklabel for the second plot.

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Comment: code doesn't work, fixable if you define y1=rand(30,1); same for y2

Comment: I added y1 and y2 values to the question. but even, you can consider both of them as the random functions. because my question is about their x and y value is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding two lines of code.  You can tweak the starting value and the step size to get the aesthetics you want using [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html), [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html), and [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html).

```
set(gca,'XTick',[0 2:2:61],'XTickLabel',[0 2:2:30 2:2:30])
xlim([0 62])
```

[image: Example demonstrating repeated x values on x tick labels]

Other approaches may be more efficient but hopefully this lets you keep moving forward.

As already pointed out in the comments, [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) may work well too.

[image: Subplot Example]

```
figure
s(1) = subplot(1,2,1)
b1 = bar(1:30,y1,'r');
s(2) = subplot(1,2,2)
b2 = bar(1:30,y2,'b');
title(s(1),'Function 1')
title(s(2),'Function 2')

% Cosmetics
xRng = [0 31];
yRng = [0 max(max(s(1).YLim),max(s(2).YLim))];
for k = 1:2
xlim(s(k),xRng)
s(k).YLim = yRng;   % Ensure both vertical axes are same (for fair comparison)
s(k).YGrid = 'on';
end
```

---

Tested with MATLAB R2017a

Comment: @Taraneh, added a 2nd option (already pointed out in comments)

Comment: That's great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not fundamentally different from the second part of [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559312/2627163) but suggests some improved technics for the 'cosmetics':

```
sp(1) = subplot(1,2,1);
bar(1:30,y1,'r');
sp(2) = subplot(1,2,2);
bar(1:30,y2,'b');
% set both y-axis to the same limits:
linkaxes(sp,'xy')
xlim([0 31])
sp(2).YTickLabel = [];
% tight the 2 subplots:
space = sp(2).Position(1)-sp(1).Position(1)-sp(1).Position(3);
sp(1).Position(3) = sp(1).Position(3)+0.5*space;
sp(2).Position(3) = sp(2).Position(3)+0.5*space;
sp(2).Position(1) = sp(2).Position(1)-0.5*space;
% create legend for both plots
legend([sp.Children],{'Function 1','Function 2'})
```

[image]

Comment: I like this. My only issue is the first 'x=30' and the second 'x=0' are so close it almost resembles 'x=300'.  You taught me some spacing commands and the `linkaxes` command which is very convenient. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome :) I was also uncomfortable with the adjacent x ticks from both axes but wasn't sure how the OP would like to solve that.